# Shorten a .gif file with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to shorten a `.gif` file through `FFmpeg`?

I need to upload a `.gif` but the service I'm using only allows a max filesize of `30mb` (the file is `35.4mb`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.gif` is an extremely inefficient format for video files.

**If you are flexible with the format, the best option is to convert the file to** `.mp4`:  This will reduce the file size by an enormous degree without significant loss of quality.  In many cases it can reduce the file size of a `.gif` by a factor of 100x or more.  Use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.gif -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

Replace `input.gif` with the source filename and `output.mp4` with the desired name for the new file.

---

If you need the format to be `.gif`, **you can shorten the animation** to reduce the size.  To do this, you will need to define start and end times in `ffmpeg`.

Here is an example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.gif -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:03 -c copy output.gif
```

- `-ss` defines the start time in `HH:MM:SS`
- `-to` defines the end time.
- You can also use `-t` to specify duration instead of end time.
- You can add a decimal point to indicate milliseconds. (ex. `00:00:05.5`)

---

**A *third* option would be to scale down the dimensions of the image**:

```
ffmpeg -i input.gif -vf "scale=iw/2:ih/2" output.gif
```

- This will halve the image dimensions, and roughly quarter the file size.  You can scale this down even further by changing the value. For example, `scale=iw/3:ih/3` will result in an image with one third the original dimensions.

Comment: Thank you so much! 
Very helpful.

Comment: You can also do: `ffmpeg -i input.gif -vf "scale=iw/2:ih/2" output.mp4` to manually control scale but save in mp4 format. This will significantly reduce the output size

Answer (score 0):

With the GNU Image Manipulation Program (GIMP) you can edit GIF files. In Ubuntu 20.04  you can install GIMP from the Software app, or from the command line by running:

```
sudo apt install gimp
```

If you want to remove some frames from a GIF file, open it in GIMP, then remove the layers (frames) you don't want. Another option would be to resize the image: go to **Image > Scale Image...** and scale the image to the proportion you want.

Once you have edited the image, go to **File > Export As...**. Make sure that the filename extension is `.gif` and click **Export**. Select the **As animation** option and edit the animation settings below, then click **Export** again.

Comment: thank you!
I will try this as well.